# "@" Decorator (in Python)

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, decorator, setter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

What function does the "class decorator"/"method decorator" (`@`) serve? In other words, what is the difference between this and a normal comment?

Also, what does `setter` do when using `@previousMethod.setter` before a method? Thank you.

Comment: A decorator is not a comment. Check [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) for what they are. As for the latter note, it's using [``property()``](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to avoid getters/setters in favour of attributes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Answer (score 5):

```
@decorator
def function(args):
    #body
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def function(args):
    #body

function = decorator(function)
```

That's really it.

As you see, the decorator gets called, so it's by no means a comment.