# Is a Python Decorator the same as Java annotation, or Java with Aspects?

Tags: java, python, python-decorators, java-annotations

Are Python Decorators the same or similar, or fundamentally different to Java annotations or something like Spring AOP, or Aspect J?

Comment: Python also has annotations, so I assume they're fundamentally different.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["@" Decorator (in Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191561/decorator-in-python)

Comment: See edits to expand question to Java aspects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Python decorators are just syntactic sugar for passing a function to another function and replacing the first function with the result:

```
@decorator
def function():
    pass
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def function():
    pass
function = decorator(function)
```

Java annotations by themselves just store metadata, you must have something that inspects them to add behaviour.

Java AOP systems are huge things built on top of Java, decorators are just language syntax with little to no semantics attached, you can't really compare them.

Answer (score 33):

This is a very valid question that anyone dabbling in both these languages simultaneously, can get. I have spent some time on python myself, and have recently been getting myself up to speed with Java and here's my take on this comparison.

Java annotations are - just that: annotations. They are markers; containers of additional metadata about the underlying object they are marking/annotating. Their mere presence doesn't change execution flow of the underlying, or doesn't add encapsulation/wrapper of some sort on top of the underlying. So how do they help? They are read and processed by - Annotation Processors. The metadata they contain can be used by custom-written annotation processors to add some auxiliary functionality that makes lives easier; BUT, and again, they NEITHER alter execution flow of an underlying, NOR wrap around them.

The stress on "not altering execution flow" will be clear to someone who has used python decorators. Python decorators, while being similar to Java annotations in look and feel, are quite different under the hood. They take the underlying and wrap themselves around it in any which way, as desired by the user, possibly even completely avoiding running the underlying itself as well, if one chooses to do so. They take the underlying, wrap themselves around it, and replace the underlying with the wrapped ones. They are effectively 'proxying' the underlying!

Now *that* is quite similar to how Aspects work in Java! Aspects per se are quite evolved in terms of their mechanism and flexibility. But in essence what they do is - take the 'advised' method (I am talking in spring AOP nomenclature, and not sure if it applies to AspectJ as well), wrap functionality around them, along with the predicates and the likes, and 'proxy' the 'advised' method with the wrapped one.

Please note these musings are at a very abstract and conceptual level, to help get the big picture. As you start delving deeper, all these concepts - decorators, annotations, aspects - have quite an involving scope. But at an abstract level, they are very much comparable.

**TLDR**

In terms of look and feel, python decorators can be considered similar to Java annotations, but under the hood, they work very very similar to the way Aspects work in Java.

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: for java annotations, still not understanding of "not altering execution flow" as that sort of goes against "add some auxiliary functionality" in my head. probably will have to go through examples to fully grok this

Comment: python decorators can only be specified on class and function declaration while you may annotate a field using java annotations.

Comment: @dtc In java, the original function remains what it is. A generated subclass or proxy will do the wrapping. Only in combination with a dependency injection framework like spring it will seem like the wrapper replaced the original function (because you are calling the subclass or proxy not the original class you hand-coded)

Answer (score 2):

I use both of them in a similar way: to turn on/off debugging or testing options.

For example (Python decorators):

```
def measure_time(func):
    def _measure_time(*args, **kwargs):
        t0 = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "time=%lf" % (time.time()-t0)
        ...
        return ret
    return _measure_time


@measure_time
def train_model(self):
    ...
```

For Java annotations, use [getAnnotation, etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) can do the similar jobs or more complicated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Python decorators and Java Annotations share de same syntax but to two very different purposes!  They aren't compatible or interchangeable for none way!

On a recent project, I had the necessity to use the java annotation semantics on a python script, and I searched a way to emulate it and found this:

In Python there are a functionality called 'Docstring'!

It is nothing more than a special comment line that have to be the first line in a module, class or function!

Like a comment line, you can use any form of text.   But what make it so special to me in this case is that is readable by python instrospection!!

So, it works like a Java Annotation, that too needs the Java reflection to interpret and react to metadata carried from it!!

Follow a short example:

Source a.py

````
```
def some_function():
    '''@myJavaLikeAnnotation()'''
    ... (my function code) ...
```
````

Source b.py (where I have to process the @myJavaLikeAnnotacion()):

```
import a

for element_name in dir(a):
    element = getattr(a, element_name)
    if hasattr(element, '__call__'):
        if not inspect.isbuiltin(element):
            try:
                doc = str(element.__doc__)
                if not doc == '@myJavaLikeAnnotation()':
                    # It don't have the 'java like annotation'!
                    break

                ... It have! Do what you have to do...  
            except:
                pass
```

Obviously that disadvantages is to have to parse by yourself all the metadata that you use in your 'python java like annotations'!